# How to call variable between two functions

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I need a clarification I am getting a error **Uncaught ReferenceError: cir is not defined** I can identify why the error is but I am unable to solve. can anyone help me

```
    function onMouseUp(event) {i++;
                    circles.push(circle);
                    var cir = new Group();
                    cir.addChild(circle);
                    createElem('circle', i);
}
```

This is a function to create element,

```
function createElem(id, i){
            var exist = document.getElementById('markList');
            c1 = document.createElement('div');
            var text = document.createTextNode(id+" "+i);
            c1.appendChild(text);
            c1.setAttribute('id', id+'_'+i);
            c1.onclick = function (){
                cir.removeChildren(i, i+1);

            };
            exist.appendChild(c1);  
        }
```

Comment: you can use [cir] as parameter for [createElem] function. Maybe call this funciton like this: [createElem('circle', i, cir)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the `cir` to `createElem`, function.....

```
function onMouseUp(event) {i++;
                    circles.push(circle);
                    cir = new Group();
                    cir.addChild(circle);
                    createElem('circle', i,cir);
}

function createElem(id, i,cir){
            var exist = document.getElementById('markList');
            c1 = document.createElement('div');
            var text = document.createTextNode(id+" "+i);
            c1.appendChild(text);
            c1.setAttribute('id', id+'_'+i);
            c1.onclick = function (){
                cir.removeChildren(i, i+1);

            };
            exist.appendChild(c1);  
        }
```

**EDIT:  Demo**

```
<script>
onMouseUp();
function onMouseUp() {

                    var cir = 1;
                    var i=1;
                    createElem('circle', i,cir);
}
function createElem(id, i,cir){
         var  fun=function (){
                alert(cir);
            };
            fun();
        }
 </script>
```

Comment: **createElement()** take cir as undefined and so result is **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'removeChildren' of undefined**

Comment: I don't think having global variables is a good practice. instead, I'd rather pass it as a parameter in createElem

Comment: @EduardGamonal Initialy, I didn't see `createElem` called in `onMouseUp`, now edited my answer

Comment: I thinks we shoud not create too many global variables. Because it's hard to be control when coding.

Comment: @Stiger thanks.. I will take it as an advice...next time :) by the way...I thought above solution works...but the OP saying something in first comment that it doesn't work still

Comment: @Devan I have created a demo in the edit of my answer.... it's working...passing parameter works....if it doesn't work for you....there must be something other than this not working in your other code....  :)